# How to go through all the numbers between -1 and 1 with numpy.arange()?

Tags: python, numpy, random-walk

I am trying to write a code for random walk, and in the direction part, I met this problem. I want the direction to be any degrees, what I do is try to use py.arrange to generate as many numbers as possible between -1 and 1. I want to ask is there any better solutions to go through all the numbers between -1 and 1? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
def fill_walk(self):
    while len(self.x_values)<self.num_points:
        x_direction=choice(np.arange(-1,1,0.00001))
        x_distance=(int(1))
        x_step=x_direction*x_distance

        y_direction=choice(np.arange(-1,1,0.00001))
        y_distance=(int(1))
        y_step=y_direction*y_distance
```

Comment: Isn't a random walk associated with random?

Comment: There is an infinite number of numbers between `-1` and `1`. Constrained to floating point numbers: there is a *very, very large* number of numbers between `-1` and `1`. Do you really need all of them?

Comment: What do you mean by "all numbers between -1 and 1"? If mean integer, it is zero, if it is not integer, then it is not a finite set of numbers.

Comment: why do you need a range of numbers between `-1` and `1` for a random walk?

Comment: Use [`random.uniform(-1, 1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform)

Comment: the documentation on `np.arange` tells you `When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.`(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) - surely a thing to be useful for random steps without bias introduced by `np.arrange()`. `random.random()*2-1` would give you values you need without creating huge numbers of numbers beforehand - not sure how its optimized unter the hood. - nevermind @PatrickHaugh `random.uniform(-1,1)` is even nicer...

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you asked for "a better solution": the random walks do not have to be simulated (even though this might be cool). You can get the matlab code of the original publication [on Leo Gradys website](http://leogrady.net/publications/), this might helt implementing something similar in python.

If you just want the random numbers, I'd refer to the comment of Patrick Haugh and use [random.uniform(-1, 1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform).